# MessageConsumer receive method is not reading message from remote machine Queue

Tags: java, activemq-classic

```
public class MessageReceiver {
    // URL of the JMS server
    private static String url = "tcp://atuleusbduv012.aemud.com:61616";
    // default broker URL is : tcp://localhost:61616"
    // Name of the queue we will receive messages from
    private static String subject = "activemq.test.incoming.master"; 
    // Queue Name.You can create any/many queue names as per your requirement.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
        // Getting JMS connection from the server
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("agile","123456789",url);
        //ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        // Creating session for sending messages
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        System.out.println("session :: "+session.toString());
        // Getting the queue 'amd.tmpesb.sapphire.incoming.master'
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
        System.out.println("destination :: "+destination.toString());       
        // MessageConsumer is used for receiving (consuming) messages
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        System.out.println("consumer :: "+consumer.toString()); 
        // Here we receive the message.
        Message message = consumer.receive();
        System.out.println("message :: "+message.toString());
        // We will be using TestMessage in our example. MessageProducer sent us a TextMessage
        // so we must cast to it to get access to its .getText() method.
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received message '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Above code is not reading messages from queue, when i debug the java class i found that , "Execution is stopped at `consumer.receive();` method i.e., it is continuously trying to read messages but not able to read.
Please let me know, what i am missing in above `MessageReceiver`  class

Also for some more details of sending/writing message to above queue.
We am using below class to send messages to queue `activemq.test.incoming.master` and is sending the messages successfully

```
public class MessageSender {    
    //URL of the JMS server. DEFAULT_BROKER_URL will just mean that JMS server is on localhost
    private static String url = "tcp://atuleusbduv012.aemud.com:61616";
    //private static String url = "tcp://localhost:61616";  
    // default broker URL is : tcp://localhost:61616"
    private static String subject = "activemq.test.incoming.master"; 
    // Queue Name.You can create any/many queue names as per your requirement.      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {        
        // Getting JMS connection from the server and starting it
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("agile","123456789",url);
        //ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();     
        //Creating a non transactional session to send/receive JMS message.
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);         
        //Destination represents here our queue 'JCG_QUEUE' on the JMS server. 
        //The queue will be created automatically on the server.
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);         
        // MessageProducer is used for sending messages to the queue.
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);     
        // We will send a small text message saying 'Hello World!!!' 
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello !!! Welcome to the world of ActiveMQ.");     
        // Here we are sending our message!
        producer.send(message);     
        System.out.println("JCG printing@@ '" + message.getText() + "'");
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

I request you to let me know what I am missing in the above `MessageReceiver` class due to which it is not reading messages from the queue `activemq.test.incoming.master`.

Comment: Are you sure that execution is stopped? What output do you see from the receiver class, if you run it _not_ in a debugger?

Comment: if you start MessageReceiver before MessageSender this must work even if you have disabled persistence of ActiveMQ but if persistence is not disabled have to work iin any case

Comment: @ Robin Green - if i  run receiver ..No output

Comment: @Hassen Bennour - tried starting MessageReceiver before sender but no luck i.e.,  No output

Comment: your ActiveMQ web console shows connected consumers ? pending messages ?

Comment: I have used threads to send and receive messages .Reference [http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html ] Thanks All

Comment: No output at all? You should at least see session, destination etc. - do you not see them?

Comment: session and destination are created .           
Also as per my understanding , execution of program is stopped at line `Message message = consumer.receive(); `      it is continuously trying to read messages but not able to find or read one may be due to session ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used threads concept to read and write messages to Queues .
Reference Link http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html 
with which `receiver` can wait for some time to receive message `consumer.receive(3000)` and also after trying to receive wait for sometime to produce more messages using `Thread.sleep(300)` with which we will be able to read and write messages to Queues in Remote Machine.
Thanks All